# Viewmodel collection and other objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Being a relative newcomer to MVC I'm musing over a little problem. I'm developing a page which relies on a collection of my viewmodel objects. All good. But, as the page has relatively complex functionality I need to get at other objects or collections of the main domain model to display in the UI. Admitedly rather more light weight objects. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: do it in the controller.  the viewmodel should be a DTO, and not contain any logic

Comment: My viewmodel class definition serves as layer on top of the DTO (which doesn't contain any logic). What's best way to deliver it to the view? Via ViewBag or in server-side mark-up blocks, i.e. @{ .. }?

Comment: Add properties to the model, set properties in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is create a custom class to encapsulate ANY data I need to display in any certain view / action. So for my Admin areas User controller, I have a AdminUserIndexViewModel class that holds my list of user business objects. I also put any other data I need to display into this class.

For my AdminUserEditViewModel (that corresponds to my Admin Area, User Controller, Edit Action) I might have a single User class, which itself has its Roles attached to modify if need be. If you need to put other information like user settings, or preferences, etc...

Comment: OK, that sounds like the best solution... sort of a viewmodel facade class.

Comment: You already said you were using viewmodels - this is a viewmodel by definition.

Comment: Yes you're right Adam, sorry for the confusion. I think that's where I was getting confused, I was just typing the view with a collection of the main entity objects. Which I was making the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not part of the viewmodel you are currently working with then you can use Html.Action to call into another controller method to render another inline view through a controllers method.

Comment: OK thanks, but I'm not sure that's going to fit what I'm trying to achieve. I'm more after data to fill dropdowns, i.e. sort of key value pairs. But, your suggestion has got me thinking about other aspects of my UI!

Comment: Then use some of the html helpers for comboboxes on the net or write your own to form them from your current viewmodel.